# async function within event listener is not passing response correctly in IOS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deployment

I have four of the code below and want the functions to run asynchronously. However it is not working on IOS devices and console error is shown saying `data` is `undefined`.

```
document.addEventListener('customEvent', async (data) => {

    try {
        console.log('before function:', data);
        await inititeFunction(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('function failed:', err);
    };
});

async function inititeFunction (data) {
    console.log('inside function:', data);
}
```

this is working correctly on desktop and android devices but not IOS.
Even the first console log is showing correctly on IOS devices but when the `inititeFunction` is called, the second console log is returning `undefined`

I have tried

```
await Promise.resolve();
await inititeFunction(data);
```

and

```
let eventData = data;
await inititeFunction(eventData);
```

with no success

Comment: Which browser are you using on the iOS device? async support is only available from mobile Safari v11

Comment: Safari and chrome v16

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To confirm, you're getting `before function:` with the correct data, but the data in `inside function:` is `undefined`? That's a really weird issue, is this a simplified version of the code, or is this it? If this is all the code you have, it might even be a bug in Safari.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find the issue today when I looked at it with fresh eyes. The issue was because of a grunt process to uglify that was moving things around and the WebKit did not like the structure of the new code. Chromium had no issues with it though

Answer (score 0):

So I narrowed it down the problem to only happen after grunt uglify minimized the JS file. As part of the process, uglify moves the content of `inititeFunction` inside the `try` creating this

```js
document.addEventListener("customEvent", async function(data) {
    try {
        await
        function(data) {
            console.log('inside function:', data);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('function failed:', err);
    };
});
```

and `WebKit` does not like the same variable name `data` for both of them and was returning undefined but Chromium had no issue with it.

I fixed the problem by just using a different variable name, `eventData`.

```js
document.addEventListener('customEvent', async (data) => {

    try {
        console.log('before function:', data);
        await inititeFunction(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('function failed:', err);
    };
});

async function inititeFunction (eventData) {
    console.log('inside function:', eventData);
}
```